# Lighttpd full URL rewrite to the path

Tags: webserver, lighttpd

I need to rewrite all possible request to the path of the server

Example: If I enter `https://wwww.myhost.com/#hi=random+text+1?stop=now`

I need a redirect to:

```
http://myhost.com/
```

It is possible with **url.rewrite**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are you really trying to achieve? Do you want to hide the urls so that it always shows http://myhost.com. I believe that is not possible if you have more than one page.

Are you trying to redirect everything to for example index.php

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?anything=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This way for example http://myhost.com/example/ will be handled like the request was http://myhost.com/index.php?anything=example